# Insert new line every 4 items in a string?

Tags: c#, sql, count, newline, stringbuilder

I have a string that sets up thumbnails one after the other with no line breaks. Images wrap down to the next line once they reach the max width of the area they are in. I want to insert a line break after every 4th thumbnail, and the code I have nearly works, but it keeps adding a new line after the 1st image -- this looks wrong. With 7 thumbnail images, there should only be one line break added and that would be after the 4th image.

Here is the class information that is used to call upon and build the string with thumbnail info from the SQL database:

```
protected List<GlassItem> GetGlassItems(Guid CurrentPage)
    {
        var items = new List<GlassItem>();
        using (MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Sitefinity"].ToString()))
        {
            cn.Open();

            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT id, BrandID, GlassName, Thumbnail, LargeImage, Ordinal, (SELECT Window_Brands.BrandName FROM Window_Brands WHERE Window_Brands.BrandPage = BrandID) AS BrandName FROM Window_Brand_cutglass WHERE BrandID = ?PageID AND Thumbnail IS NOT NULL AND LargeImage IS NOT NULL ORDER BY Ordinal", cn);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("PageID", CurrentPage.ToString()));

            using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    if (reader["Thumbnail"].ToString().Length > 1 && reader["LargeImage"].ToString().Length > 1)
                    {
                        items.Add(new GlassItem
                        {
                            LargeImagePath = Revere.GetImagePath(reader["LargeImage"].ToString()),
                            ThumbnailPath = Revere.GetImagePath(reader["Thumbnail"].ToString()),
                            GlassName = reader["GlassName"].ToString()
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
            cn.Close();
        }
        return items;
    }
```

This is the bit of code that makes use of the GetGlassItems class. This is where a new line is meant to be inserted after every 4th item, but is also adding a new line after the first item:

```
protected String BuildCutGlass(Guid CurrentPage)
 {
        var items = GetGlassItems(new Guid(CurrentPage.ToString()));
        StringBuilder Glass = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
        {
            Glass.Append(String.Format("<div class='GlassItem'><a href='{0}' class='CutGlassPopup Icon'><img src='{1}' alt='{2}' width='77' height='77' /></a><a href='{0}' class='CutGlassPopup'>{2}</a></div>",
                                        items[i].LargeImagePath,
                                        items[i].ThumbnailPath,
                                        items[i].GlassName));
            Console.Write("count: " + items.Count.ToString() + "<br />");
            if (i == 4)
            {
                // new line every 4 items
                Glass.Append("<div style='clear: both;'></div>");
            }
        }

        return Glass.ToString();
    }
```

How can I edit the above code so that a new line is no longer being added after the first thumbnail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a check with [modulus operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx).

```
if (i % 4 == 0)
```

This will let you insert a new row every fourth row.

But this will insert a new line for the first item as well, since `i` would be `0` and `0 % 4` would return `0`. So modify your check as:

```
if(i != 0 && i % 4 == 0)
```

Your current check `i == 4`  will add an extra line only after the first four lines.

Comment: I tried the modulus check, but I get the same exact problem: a new line is added after the 1st thumbnail, then after every 4th one. I don't know why it has to keep putting a new line after the 1st item, but it's not what I want to happen.

Comment: @SaraDeJaneiro 0 % 0 == 0.  Set up an exclusion for that in your if statement.

Comment: @Habib Shouldn't it be (i-1) % 4 == 0 ?? Your example prints one after lines zero and four. We want after index three.

Comment: @SaraDeJaneiro, Just add an modify your check  to `if(i != 0 && i % 4 == 0)` I have modified the answer as well.

Comment: @MarkBalhoff, shouldn't it be `(i + 1) % 4`, since if you want a new line on index 3 then 3 + 1..., But I will leave that for the OP

Comment: @Habib That worked out perfectly for me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Habib yes sorry i + 1 not i - 1. Not sure what I was thinking.